# Powwering Raspberry pi 3 with Li-ion battery

Tags: pi-3b+

I use MT3608 boost converter in order to convert Li-ion voltage to 5V for RPI, but when I connect battery, RPI doesn't boot up. When I check output of MT3608 it is 5V but it can't tolerate peak currents at boot up. What boost converter I can use?

Comment: Cheap LM2596 5V 3A PSU modules are good for Rpi